# Как при нажатии на кнопку перезагрузить страницу и выполнить функцию?

Tags: javascript

Есть тест который проходится на сайте и по окончанию теста нужно что бы при нажатие на кнопку 'повторить тест' страница обновлялась и после загрузки страницы выполнялась функция которая будет начинать тест заново и приводить к первому вопросу

условно у нас есть 4 дива в которых кнопки, каждая кнопка открывает следующий див но последняя закрывает всё, как сделать так что бы она перезагружала страницу и после перезагрузки выполняла какой то код

```
<div class="new__year_overlay">
  <div class="step_1"><button></button></div>
  <div class="step_1"><button></button></div>
  <div class="step_1"><button></button></div>
  <div class="step_1"><button></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: И в чём, собственно, сложность? Код в студию

Comment: @Object417 могу указать код, но мне просто нужен пример потому что у меня в массиве хранятся данные и исчезают только после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: и откуда берутся эти данные перед первым тестированием?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Перезагрузить страницу можно так
window.location.reload()

// Выполнить функцию, как только страница загрузится
window.onload = () => {
    myFunc1()
    myFunc2()
    //etc
}
```

При текущем раскладе ничего более посоветовать не могу.